# fprintf() and fread() usage with .txt files

Tags: c, file, hex, printf, fread

If I were to use

```
fprintf(fp, "%d", 1);
```

to write in a `txt` file, would the content of my file be of *hexadecimal* value 1, or 31? (ASCII value for '1')

Also, how exactly does `fread()` function read data?
I have a file with 2 bytes, of hexadecimal value 32 and 33 (respectively).
This is my code:

```
struct S {char a,b;} x; 
FILE *f = fopen("F.TXT","rb"); 
if (f) { 
   fread(&x,1,sizeof(x),f); 
   printf("1:%c\n", x.b); 
   printf("2:%c\n", x.a); 
}
```

The output is the following:

```
1:3
2:2
```

Why is that?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. 0x33 is a hex value of the ASCII for `3`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Not a problem, just wish to know how exactly fread handles data.

Comment: `fread` is reading binary data. `printf` is interpreting it as directed by the format string.

Comment: `fprintf(fp, "%d", 1);` writes an character (ASCII) `'1'` to the file.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the prototype for `fread` is `fread(void, size of element, number of elements, FILE *);`, I read 1 element of 2 bytes, why isn't that assigned to value of `x.a` with overflow? why is it assigned to `a` and `b` correctly?

Comment: @NerminaAvdić - In memory the struct is laid out as two consecutive bytes. The first byte is the `x.a` and the second byte is `x.b`. The `fread` then copies the two bytes from the file into the memory where `x` starts. Consequently the first byte from the file will end up as `a` and the second byte from the file will end up as `b`.

Comment: get book and find section with binary and text modes on files

Comment: In printing section change order of printing a and b. you said the file content is: `23` 32 is hex value for 2 number in ASCII system and 33 is for 3. Note that using fread in that form reads exactly two bytes from file whoch means reading 2 and 3 numbers and put them in X structure elements a and b

Comment: now use print a then print b to see in correct way

Answer (score 0):

To answer the OPs first question:

given this statement:

```
fprintf(fp, "%d", 1);
```

the contents of the file would be a single char containing:

```
0x31
```

which is the hex value for the ASCII character: 1